# I have an error that firestore query does not return any results - Kotlin - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

**I passed the hard string in the parameter, but it still doesn't return the expected result**
Here I've got an Init function to launch first

```
@HiltViewModel
class WordsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val words_coursesService: Words_CoursesService,
    logService: LogService
) : LearningEnglishAppViewModel(logService){

    var words = mutableStateListOf<Words>()

    init {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val wordsList =  words_coursesService.getWordsFromCourses("08IZV3EvqKKPw7z85Sdr")
                words.clear() 
                words.addAll(wordsList.filterNotNull()) 
            }

        resetGame()
    }
}
```

And below is my query function:

```
 override suspend fun getWordsFromCourses(coursesId: String): List<Words?> {
        val wordsCoursesQuery = firestore.collection(WORDS_COURSES_COLLECTION)
            .whereEqualTo(COURSES_ID_FIELD, coursesId)
            .get()
            .await()

        val listWordsCourses = wordsCoursesQuery.toObjects<Words_Courses>()

        val listWords = mutableListOf<Words?>()

        for (wordsCourses in listWordsCourses) {
            val wordsDocument = firestore.collection(WORDS_COLLECTION)
                .document(wordsCourses.wordsId)
                .get()
                .await()

            val words = wordsDocument.toObject<Words>()
            listWords.add(words)
        }
        return listWords
```

}

And this is my firestore
[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to get the Words_Courses objects through the coursesId field on the firestore, then get these objects to get the wordsId field to get the Words objects.
Although I have the following query:
  val wordsCoursesQuery = firestore.collection(WORDS_COURSES_COLLECTION)
             .whereEqualTo(COURSES_ID_FIELD, coursesId)
             .get()
             .await()
As you can see in the picture, I didn't enter anything wrong, the argument I passed also tried hardening the string but the result still didn't return the desired Words_Courses objects. Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry everyone, my problem has been solved, it was really difficult, because I placed the resetGame() function outside viewModelScope.launch, so the resetGame function always runs first without waiting for the data to finish loading.Leads to words always giving a null error

```html
    init {
        val coursesId = savedStateHandle.get<String>(COURSES_ID)
        if (coursesId != null) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val wordsList = words_coursesService.getWordsFromCourses(coursesId.idFromParameter())
                words.clear() // Xóa tất cả các phần tử hiện có trong mutableStateListOf<Words>
                words.addAll(wordsList.filterNotNull()) // Thêm danh sách từ wordsList sau khi loại bỏ các phần tử null
                resetGame()
            }
        }
    }
```